# How to get view count of every page on site and add that (increasing) number to Dashboard Widget

Tags: admin, dashboard

I don't really have any code, but I'm trying to get the page views of every page on a WordPress site (and every time I hit refresh, the number of page views should increase). I would also like it so I could output that increasing number into a **dashboard widget**. A bit of complex code I would imagine, but I have no idea where to even start with this.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate page views count without any plugins. What you need to do is create a post meta key for each post (of course automatically) and increase the counter of this post meta key on each post/page load or visit.

So here is the function to create a post meta key `post_views_count` for each post and calling this function on each page/post load will increase post count by one.

```
// Post views function
function wps_set_post_views( $postID ) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, true );
    if ( $count=='' ){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta( $postID, $count_key );
        add_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, '0' );
    } else {
        $count++;
        update_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, $count );
    }
}
```

Now you need to call this function from `single.php` and `page.php`. Just paste this on these pages. If you use [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) or similar cache plugin then you will need to use fragment caching to make sure function is called on each page load.

```
<?php wps_post_views( get_the_ID() ); ?>
```

This will set you post/page views and increase counter by one on each visit.

Now if you want to add post views on admin column then you can add a column for post views like this.

```
// Get post views
function wps_get_post_views( $postID ) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, true );
    if ( $count=='' ){
        delete_post_meta( $postID, $count_key );
        add_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, '0' );
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}

// Add to admin post column
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'posts_column_views' );
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_column_views', 5, 2 );
function posts_column_views( $defaults ) {
    $defaults['post_views'] = __('Views');
    return $defaults;
}
function posts_custom_column_views( $column_name, $id ){
  if ( $column_name === 'post_views' ) {
        echo wps_get_post_views( get_the_ID() );
    }
}
```

That's it. All these functions will go in functions.php file except the code for `single.php` and `page.php` to call function to set post views.

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins out there showing the site's statistics along with the popular posts/pages with their reading count.

- [Jetpack by WordPress.com](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/) - has a nice site statistics module

And there are others too...

- [Google search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=Site%20stats%20plugin%20wordpress)
- [WordPress plugin repo search result](https://wordpress.org/search/Site+Statisitcs)

Most of them even provide a short stat view dashboard widget from where you can see the basic information too.